# Views not properly contained within single list item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

My goal is to pull three `JSON Objects` from an adapter and display them as three text views in one `list item`. It should look like this when only one set of objects in present:
[image]

Instead it's showing this:

[image]

I can't see anything wrong in my XML or adapter. (Shown Below) What can cause the textviews to split into more list items than desired like this?

```
list_item.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/outer"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="#08445e"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Room "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time: "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/inner"
        android:background="#d1d1d1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/outer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#dc2f2f"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Mark Done"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainAdapter.Java:

```
package com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();

    public MainAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<String>arrayList){
        this.context=context;
        this.arraylist=arrayList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        Button   mark_btn;
        public TextView textViewRoom;
        public TextView textViewRequest;
        public TextView textViewTime;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        View convertView=row;
       final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

            holder.mark_btn= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.textViewRoom = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRoom);
            holder.textViewRequest = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRequest);
            holder.textViewTime = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        holder.textViewRoom.setText(arraylist.get(position));
        holder.textViewRequest.setText(arraylist.get(position));
        holder.textViewTime.setText(arraylist.get(position));

        holder.mark_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Marked complete", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.anwarshahriar.calligrapher.Calligrapher;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String URL_DATA = 
"https://summerproject17.herokuapp.com/api/request/?format=json";
    private ListView recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<String> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       /* recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));*/
//is the below line newly added?
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();

        Calligrapher calligrapher = new Calligrapher(this);
        calligrapher.setFont(this, "elegantluxpro-mager.ttf", true);

    }


    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = 
jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                              /*  ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                        o.getString("room"),
                                        o.getString("request"),
                                        o.getString("unixTime")
                                );*/
                                listItems.add(o.getString("room"));
                                listItems.add(o.getString("request"));
                                listItems.add(o.getString("room"));
                            }

                            Log.e("size",""+listItems.size());

                            adapter = new 
MainAdapter(MainActivity.this,listItems);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml list view portion:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

</ListView>
```

Note: I asked a similar question a week or so back but this is different in that the structure of the list items has changed and more details have been provided in this question.

Comment: Try 'HashMap<String,String>'. It will give you key value pair.

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to pull 3 JSON Objects from an adapter and display them as 3 text views in one list item. It should look like this when only one set of objects in present:

The list adapter is designed to have a 1 to 1 map with the list that is backing it. Therefore your approach above is somewhat flawed as I understand it. If you want three JSON Objects to be displayed as the three `TextView`s of a **single list item**, you need to translate to another List comprised of (for example) the class `ViewHolder` which you defined. Look up `ListView` using custom adapter for this. Not sure why `ViewHolder` is an internal class, it can simply be a non-public class in the same file.

> I can't see anything wrong in my XML

There appear to be some redundancies in your xml layout. What you could do is define a custom layout for your list item, which would have a single `RelativeLayout` that has all the three text views and the button (something like this).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Room "
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#dc2f2f"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Mark Done"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time: "
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alignLeft="@id/button"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alignBottom="@id/textViewRoom"
        android:alignLeft="@id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you could use a combination of `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. But there is no orientation attribute in `RelativeLayout`, so you need to get rid of that as well.

Not sure if this is sufficient to solve the specific problem you were struggling with but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

As adamarta says, the there's a 1 to 1 mapping between your list & what's displayed.  1 item in your ArrayList gives you 1 item in your ListView.  A common way of doing this is creating a data model class.  It would look like this.

```
public class RoomItem {
    private String room;
    private String time;
    private String request;

    public RoomItem(String room, String request, String time) {
        this.room = room;
        this.request = request;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public RoomItem() {        
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

Your `ArrayList` declaration would change like this.

```
    private ArrayList<RoomItem> listItems;
```

And you'll have to change the `ArrayList` uses in your adapter as well.

Also, in `getView()` in the adapter, set the values like this

```
    holder.textViewRoom.setText(arraylist.get(position).getRoom());
    holder.textViewRequest.setText(arraylist.get(position).getRequest());
    holder.textViewTime.setText(arraylist.get(position).getTime());
```

In MainActivity, in `loadRecyclerViewData()`, replace your 3 current `listItems.add(...)` with this.

```
    // create a new data item with the new information
    RoomItem item = new RoomItem(o.getString("room"),
            o.getString("request"),
            o.getString("room"));)

    // then add that item to the list 
    listItems.add(item);
```

You could also create an empty item then add each field (do either this or the above code, not both)

```
    RoomItem item = new RoomItem();
    item.setRoom(o.getString("room");
    etc.
```

As for your layout, if it looks OK in the preview, then it's probably OK.  Except...
you're replacing the labels (Room & Time) with the values.  I don't think you want to do that.  I think this is what you need.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRoomLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Room: "
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="placeholder"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewRoomLabel"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTimeLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time: "
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="placeholder"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

I haven't built and tested this so I may have missed a couple of small things like needing to make changes for the new `ArrayList` etc but I think this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you. This build nicely off of adamarla's answer. You both provided amazing context on how to properly structure these. With both your help I was able to get it working. I will also post an update with more detail on the changes I implemented to get it working.

Comment: Glad to have helped